# How do I convert tag img src to url from an external store ASP net Core 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, url-rewriting, middleware

I have a lot of pages, views in my project with images. Currently, in the project, the images are taken from the local folder with the project. Example:

`<img src="images/banner.jpeg" class="img-responsive" alt="banner">`

The paths are relative. In addition, the folder with static files is not wwwroot, but different:

```
StaticFileOptions options = new StaticFileOptions();
options.FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(staticFolder.Value);
options.RequestPath = new PathString(staticFolder.Key);
options.OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
{
    ctx.Context.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] =
        "public,max-age=" + websiteSettings.ImageCacheControlDurationInSeconds;
};

app.UseStaticFiles(options);
```

I need to make that the pictures look at the absolute path, for example, https://cdntest.azureedge.net/content/products/images/banner.jpeg

Changing src to img throughout the project is not an option.

Maybe I can somehow intercept it using middleware and change the paths or do it through url rewrite.

I found example with url rewrite, but it doesn`t work:

```
        <outboundRules>
            <rule name="cdn" preCondition="html">
                <match filterByTags="Img" pattern="^images/(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" value="https://cdntest.azureedge.net/content/products/images/banner.jpeg" />
            </rule>
            <preConditions>
                <preCondition name="html">
                    <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                </preCondition>
            </preConditions>
        </outboundRules>
```

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: According to Microsoft [URL Rewriting Middleware in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-2.1), if hosting on IIS, the IIS rewriter is favored over custom-in-code middleware, otherwise, you can write your own middleware using code snippets & matching rules found in the aforementioned documentation source.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem in answer @TimothyMacharia
Code:

```
public class RedirectImageRule : IRule
{
    private readonly string _extension;
    private readonly WebsiteSettingsBase _websiteSettings;

    public RedirectImageRule(string extension,
        IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(extension))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(extension));
        }

        if (!Regex.IsMatch(extension, @"^\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$"))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid extension", nameof(extension));
        }

        _extension = extension;
        _websiteSettings = configuration.GetSection("WebsiteSettings").Get<WebsiteSettingsBase>();
    }

    public void ApplyRule(RewriteContext context)
    {
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;

        if (request.Path.Value.EndsWith(_extension, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
            response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently;
            context.Result = RuleResult.EndResponse;

           if (request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/images"))
            {
                response.Headers[HeaderNames.Location] =
                    CreateUri(request.Path.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                response.Headers[HeaderNames.Location] =
                    CreateUri(request.Path.Value, isAddFolder: true);
            }
        }
    }

    private string CreateUri(string path, bool isAddFolder = false)
    {
        var baseUri = new Uri(_websiteSettings.CdnStoragePath);

        if (!isAddFolder)
        {
            return new Uri(baseUri, path).AbsoluteUri;
        }

        if (path.StartsWith("/"))
        {
            return $"{_websiteSettings.CdnStorageContentFolderPath}{path}";
        }

        return $"{_websiteSettings.CdnStorageContentFolderPath}/{path}";
    }
}
```

And use it:

```
var options = new RewriteOptions();

options.AddIISUrlRewrite(env.ContentRootFileProvider, "IISUrlRewrite.xml")
.Add(new RedirectImageRule(".png", configuration))
.Add(new RedirectImageRule(".jpg", configuration))
.Add(new RedirectImageRule(".svg", configuration));
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, asp.net core doesn't support outbound rule rewrite. The only way is using this rule by using the IIS url rewrite module.

You could publish this application and host on the IIS, then you could install this [extension](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) and add below url rewrite rule inside the web.config file.

Web.config settings like below:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <outboundRules>
            <rule name="test" preCondition="html">
                <match filterByTags="Img" pattern="^images/(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" value="https://cdntest.azureedge.net/content/products/images/banner.jpeg" />
            </rule>
            <preConditions>
                <preCondition name="html">
                    <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                </preCondition>
            </preConditions>
        </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```